# how to find a dangling namespace or preprocessor directive in an enormous codebase

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

We suspect there is such a thing in our code,

so maybe an `#ifdef` without the `#endif` or perhaps a namespace foo `{` without the `}`, what are some tactics for locating such a thing in a codebase with hundreds of thousands of files, is there a way to use regular expressions?

EDIT - forgot to mention (this is the really evil part) there are what we call unity files generated in this code that pull every single cpp file into one big super cpp file. Therefore the compiler will probably not report about missing braces or mismatched else/ifs because they can easily run on into the next few hundred million lines of code...

Comment: Good question... this has dogged programmers for ages. Sounds like it's time to get out the Red Bull.

Comment: I work in a very high office...

Comment: Are you getting a compile error?

Comment: yup, it can't find the definition of a class, thinks I'm trying to inline a data declaration.

Comment: This sort of thing drives me mad.  One moment, everything is fine.  Next, nearly every module is throwing dozens of errors. I've been know to remove whole chunks of modules from my project in a binary-chop fashion in an attempt to narrow down the error :((

Comment: Sometimes these problems are recursive #includes.  Does the first error show up in a header file?

Comment: @MartinJames: "This sort of thing drives me mad." Consider using different language. This sort of thing is a common problem that is very likely to occur. So you should learn how to deal with it without "being driven mad" every time.

Comment: @MartinJames I understand how you feel!

Comment: @MartinJames: well, normally the problem is located in your local changes (since the code on the repository compiles, obviously), so you just have to review the patch of changes you just did. If you have the good habit of making small patches (because those are easier to review), then it will be quickly located. Think of it as a way of punishing those developers with bad development practices :)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression can't really find matching braces, especially if they are nested.

The best way in my opinion is to make sure that all code is properly indented, then it's easy to see when something is missing.

Other than that, it's manual labour matching beginnings with ends. Hopefully it only has to be done very seldom. Also note that most modern text editors geared toward coding are very good at matching things like braces and parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler and preprocessor *will* complain about mismatched `#if / #endif` pairs or mismatched braces. Find the first file the compiler complains about and "fudge" it manually until it compiles.

(No, standard regular expressions cannot match pairs nested to arbitrary depth.)

Answer (score 1):

> how to find a dangling namespace or preprocessor directive in an enormous codebase

Pressing `Ctrl+]` in visual studio will cause cursor to jump to matching brace or endif statement. When you find a brace at which cursor can't jump, it is "dangling". Plus you can fold portions of code which can help you to locate mismatching brace.

I'd also recommend reading actual compiler output instead of error list.

> with hundreds of thousands of files

Terminate compilation at the first error, investigate file that causes the error, fix the error, try to compile again. Compile one file at a time using "Compile" instead of "Build solution". "Ask" compiler to produce output listing with include files inserted (/E or /P switch in VS2008 cl.exe), then investigate resulting file.

If that doesn't work either, you'll have to spend some time writing a small parser written in python/perl - the one that'll check for matching braces.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps process:

1. Use a regular build (not an horrendous unity build) to locate the error
2. If your compiler does not catch the error with the appropriate flag, switch to another one

Note that with a smart compiler, it can work even with a unity build.

Using `-Wscope` with Clang, you get a warning if a scope (such as a namespace) starts in a file (like a header) but does not end there. The patch that introduced this can be found on [the mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/cfe-commits@cs.uiuc.edu/msg46504.html). It will be available in the 3.1 release.

I do not think there is an equivalent in Clang for preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer in any way, but I did find it helpful to use this regular expression:

`// *\#if|\#el|\#en`

which searches for // followed by any amount of whitespace (including none) and then either #if, #el or #en (to exclude the possibility of throwing up all the pragma's etc - this could definitely be improved upon.

luckily I only have to search in my open documents, which is several hundred but it could be A LOT worse. Hope this helps someone in the future, this is horrible!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to NOT (effectively) paste 100000s of files into one file, so that as each file compiles the compiler will know right away at the end of there's something mismatched. Then it should be trivial to use the error message generated and normal code inspection to find the missing directive or brace.

Comment: yeah I agree! But tell it to the guys over at *major game studio* - arghargarghghghhggh!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be relevant to your problem, but I was getting an "Unexpected #else" error when framing some header files in an #if/#else/#endif block.

I found that if I set the problem modules to not use pre-compiled headers, the problem went away. Something to do with the "#pragma hdrstop" should not be within an #if/#endif.